# htaccess and server routes

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

On my preview box I have multiple sites in dev.

```
-htdocs
--site1
--site2
--site3
----assets
----system
```

When I'm writing my CSS I want to point all images to the root, (which would be the case on the live server), i.e. /assets/img/file.jpg

How would I change the root for each site

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have misunderstood what mod_rewrite does.
Mod_rewrite does NOT rewrite links, it rewrites requests, which would not be possible in your scenario.
I believe that the correct solution in your case is to use name-based virtual hosts which is supported by the Apache HTTP Server core.